# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in OS X 10.8.5 & Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: xcode, macos, appkit

I have a project that have to test compatibility on OS X 10.8, I develop it in macOS 10.12.1 & Xcode 8.1, everything works well in it. But now I test it in OS X 10.8.5 & Xcode 5.1.1, it has an error:

**Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)**

This error occur in

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil];
```

or

```
[NSApp run];
```

Q: How to fix this?

---

My project is mix C & Objective-C codes, here is the `main` function:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  [NSApplication sharedApplication];

  [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
  [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"NSDisabledDictationMenuItem"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"NSDisabledCharacterPaletteMenuItem"];

  /* Some other codes to create windows & menus... */

  AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
  [NSApp setDelegate:appDelegate];

  [NSApp run]; // => EXC_BAD_ACCESS

  return 0;
}
```

And somewhere else:

```
  if (allWindowsAreClosed) {
      [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil]; // => EXC_BAD_ACCESS
  }
```

Comment: Add some more code near to your crash point.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown; consider showing all it.

Comment: Finally I found the answer, because I use Objective-C objects inside C struct, I have to disable ARC in Xcode to make sure it compile & run properly.